# Iterate two pandas dataframe columns at the same time and return values from each column into separate places

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a solution that would make it possible to iterate two dataframe columns at the same time and then get the values from each column and put them in two separate places in a text.

My code so far:

```
def fetchingMetaTitle(x):
    keywords = df['Keyword']
    title1 = f'{x.title()} - We have a great selection of {x} | Example.com'
    title2 = f'{x.title()} - Choose among several {x} here | Example.com'
    title3 = f'{x.title()} - Buy cheap {x} easy and fast | Example.com'
    for i in keywords:
        if i.lower() in x.lower():
            return random.choice([title1,title2,title3])
    else:
        return np.nan

df['Category Meta Title'] = df['Keyword'].apply(fetchingMetaTitle)
```

Which will give me the following result:

```
+---------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Keyword | Category Title |                    Category Meta Title                    |
+---------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| jeans   | blue jeans     | Jeans - We have a great selection of jeans | Example.com  |
| jackets | red jackets    | Jackets - Choose among several jackets here | Example.com |
| shoes   | black shoes    | Shoes - Buy cheap shoes easy and fast | Example.com       |
+---------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

At the moment i'm only fetching from df['Keyword'] and i'm returning the values into df['Category Meta Title'] at two places. Instead of adding it twice i would like to add the values from df['Category Title'] as a secondary value.

So the result would be the following:

```
+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Keyword | Category Title |                      Category Meta Title                      |
+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| jeans   | blue jeans     | Jeans - We have a great selection of blue jeans | Example.com |
| jackets | red jackets    | Jackets - Choose among several red jackets here | Example.com |
| shoes   | black shoes    | Shoes - Buy cheap black shoes easy and fast | Example.com     |
+---------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this function will do what you need, using the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) syntax rather than the `f'{string}'` format:

```
def fetchingMetaTitle(row):
    title1 = '{} - We have a great selection of {} | Example.com'.format(
                     row['Keyword'].title(), row['Category Title'])
    title2 = '{} - Choose among several {} here | Example.com'.format(
                     row['Keyword'].title(), row['Category Title'])
    title3 = '{} - Buy cheap {} easy and fast | Example.com'.format(
                     row['Keyword'].title(), row['Category Title'])
    return random.choice([title1,title2,title3])

df['Category Meta Title '] = df.apply(fetchingMetaTitle, axis=1)

>>> df
   Keyword Category Title                               Category Meta Title 
0    jeans     blue jeans  Jeans - Choose among several blue jeans here |...
1  jackets    red jackets  Jackets - We have a great selection of red jac...
2    shoes    black shoes  Shoes - Buy cheap black shoes easy and fast | ...
```

Alternatively, with the `f'{string}'` method:

```
def fetchingMetaTitle(row):
    keyword = row['Keyword'].title()
    cat = row['Category Title']
    title1 = f'{keyword} - We have a great selection of {cat} | Example.com'
    title2 = f'{keyword} - Choose among several {cat} here | Example.com'
    title3 = f'{keyword} - Buy cheap {cat} easy and fast | Example.com'
    return random.choice([title1,title2,title3])

df['Category Meta Title '] = df.apply(fetchingMetaTitle, axis=1)
```

Will do the same thing.

**Note**: I'm not exactly sure what the goal of your `if` statement was, so if you clarify that, I could try to insert its functionality into the functions above...

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new column and put the template for a sentence and both of the parameters in it. This would fulfill your requirement to have access to the row values in both of you original columns. In the next step you can apply a custom function which creates the sentences for you and puts them in a `res` column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['aa','bb','cc'], 'B':['a','b','c'], 'C':['1.{}, {}', '2.{}, {}', '3.{}, {}']})

df['combined'] = df[['A','B','C']].values.tolist()
df['res'] = df['combined'].apply(lambda x: x[2].format(x[0], x[1]))

print(df['res'])
```

Using this approach, based on the following DataFrame `df`:

```
    A  B         C
0  aa  a  1.{}, {}
1  bb  b  2.{}, {}
2  cc  c  3.{}, {}
```

The output is:

```
0    1.aa, a
1    2.bb, b
2    3.cc, c
```